# LVM default created volumes: Are they standardized?

Tags: lvm

I've noticed that in my LVM setup I have

- lv_root
- lv_home
- lv_swap

Are these created by LVM for me on boot?  I haven't found any documentation on how these volumes are created.

Answer (score 0):

These were created when you installed your OS. You can create more at any time, that's the purpose of LVM.